# Aligning an input box with label and a button with CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

I would like to create the following design:

[image]

I am using react + tailwind but am more interested in the principle of how to solve this than the code so please feel free to respond with vanilla css + html or whatever you prefer or just describe your approach.

I tried something like this:

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="flex flex-row items-stretch space-x-4">
    <div class="relative flex-1 ">
      <input type="text" name="wallet" value="" id="wallet" class="block w-full px-4 py-3 text-xl" placeholder="0x0F66d8C787d5Dffa15b6F57019ABB3c99cC5Cbe2">
      <div class="mt-1">
        <label for="wallet" class="block px-5 text-right font-medium text-white">
          Address
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center px-12 py-4 text-sm font-medium">
      Proceed
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I get this:

[image]

I could imagine that the solution is to put everything in a grid element and have the Input box and the button stretch to be the same size. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Does changing `items-stretch` into `items-start` do the job?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Using `items-start` does not work out of the box since I'm using different font sizes for the input box and the button. I could try to adjust the padding in the button to compensate but it's difficult using the tailwind units to make it fit perfectly.

Comment: just a few [thoughts](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SOz6Zfng86). I would specify height of the elements if its OK for app layout

Comment: I think you are right with the specifying height option - if you post it as answer am happy to accept it.